# Static library symbols not being found even with -l

Tags: c, linker-errors

I have a static library, liborc-0.4.a with no shared library. I have another library, libschroedinger-1.0.a (no shared) that depends on symbols in liborc-0.4.a. If I run nm on liborc-0.4.a, symbols such as orc_init show up as T (meaning they are defined). I built libschroedinger-1.0.a with the command line flag -lorc-0.4 so it saw the symbols and was ok.

However, now I have a small executable that depends on libschroedinger-1.0.a. It compiles fine, but when I run the linker

```
gcc -lschroedinger-1.0 -lorc-0.4 -o output input.o
```

It gives errors such as:

```
/usr/local/lib/libschroedinger-1.0.a(libschroedinger_1.0_la-schro.o):schro.c:(.text+0x21):
undefined reference to `orc_init'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`gcc` is sensitive to the order of libraries.  When it's compiling `liborc-0.4.a` in, there is no need for `orc_init`, so it's not included.  The solution is to put the `LDFLAGS` at the end of the command:

```
gcc -o output input.o -lschroedinger-1.0 -lorc-0.4
```

Comment: The only requirement is that all libraries have their dependencies listed _after_ themselves in the compiler line. So if liba depends on libb, you write gcc ... -la -lb. If there are circular dependencies, you include the same library twice.

Comment: @johs34yp: GNU binutils ld actually supports `--start-group` `--end-group` (or `-(` `-)`), which will repeatedly scan for symbols in the libraries/archives listed in between to resolve circular dependencies.  It's not portable, though, nor is it recommended: one should avoid create circularly-dependent libraries in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably compiled libschroedinger with shared liborc. Static library is the same as bunch of object files in an archive, so they don't need to see more than headers. Write like the following to be sure (the same apples to liborc).

```
gcc /path/to/libschroedinger-1.0.a /path/to/liborc-0.4.a -o output input.o
```